# TextView hides if other text is very long

Tags: android, textview

I have this layout. My problem is, when txtName has a very long value, the txtAge cannot be seen. Please help me to solve this without using the attribute maxWidth. Thanks in advance.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need a linear layout? Or we can use a Relative layout?

Comment: yes, we can use any of those layout.

Comment: added another answer here

Answer (score 1):

Relative layout it's more good for positioning, try with this code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="30dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="9pt"
        android:text="Name Surname"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtName"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/separator"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="9pt"
        android:text="Age"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Tell me if I can helps you, good luck!

Pd: I use view as separator because I work with API >13 if you work with API >=17 you can use this commands android:layout_alignEnd="" or android:layout_alignStart="".

---

The final solution is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="30dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="9pt"
        android:text="Name Surname"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtAge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtName"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="9pt"
        android:text="Age"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: still the same. txtAge hides. :(

Comment: I try to use my code in my app, and txtAges doesn't hides, it's possible the problem is "com.klab.lods.en.custom.views.LDTextViewBold" of this component... Because if I use with my editText I don't have any problems...

Comment: I changed it to TextView and still the same behavior

Comment: Can you say me your textSize?

Comment: And txtAge should not be below txtName. it shoulg be on the right of it. Try to use TextView instead of EditText

Comment: Please try to use this text in txtName "Name Surnameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee". Age hides.

Comment: You have your solution now!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code, It is solved ur problem.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAge"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

or else,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Some n"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="age"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minEms="3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="23sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But it is not dynamic. What i want to do is, texts should always be together with each other. Giving weights is just like giving the maxWidth of the view (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use This.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.klab.lods.en.custom.views.LDTextViewBold
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

<com.klab.lods.en.custom.views.LDTextViewBold
    android:id="@+id/txtAge"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
```

Comment: If you give a weight to the TextView in the LinearLayout you should give width or height (depending if it has vertical or horizontal orientation) the value 0.

Comment: Since you've changed the width, it is not hiding. but they have the same width. It should be dynamic. If the text is too short, for example: 3 characters, there is relatively big space between each textview

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: If you want text to be together the textViews then give gravity, as i did in code

Answer (score -1):

Yo can give to your TextViews a weight like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.klab.lods.en.custom.views.LDTextViewBold
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textLarge" />

<com.klab.lods.en.custom.views.LDTextViewBold
    android:id="@+id/txtAge"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textLarge" />
```

Giving width 0dp and weight 1 to both will make them use the same space inside the LinearLayout. If you want your txtName textView be bigger than txtAge just give a higher weight to txtName.
I hope this will help you

Comment: But it is not dynamic. What i want to do is, texts should always be together with each other. Giving weights is just like giving the maxWidth of the view (I think)